# jQuery After page loaded, check if radio button selected

Tags: jquery, onload, checked

I can easily grab the `value` or check if a radio button is selected using the `.click(function()` but what I need to do if check to see if a radio button is selected and/ or grab its value after a page has loaded (i.e. some radio buttons are pre-selected on page load).

I assumed something like this might work but it doesn't:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=q22]:checked").val()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to copy something in my original answer, in case you saw it before I quickly corrected it.  Updated that. I included some other nice functionality you may be interested in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio][name='q22']:checked").val()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, had it running under (window).load and wouldn't work but under .ready its fine - thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that - ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is ok.

What you might have forgoten is to run it after page has loaded and the html has been read. You can use jQuery's **[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = $("input[type=radio][name=q22]:checked").val();
    console.log(i);
});
```

**Demo** [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zVj9h/)

Answer (score 1):

Either just put your script at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or use jQuery's [`ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready). In either case, the script will have access to the elements on the page and can get the value of the checked radio button.

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/oLujAVu/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/oLujAVu/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

used `$(document).ready(handler)`

Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

[Check This](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    // Code run after DOM load success 
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("")
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**it will alert after BODY loaded success**

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var arr=$("input[type=radio][name=q22]:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=radio][name='q22']:checked").val();
});
```

or else you can also use this :

```
    $(function(){
       if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
         // do something
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC try this

var d= $('[name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.City)"]:checked').val();